# WPF: How to create the visual tree for dynamically generated DataGrid objects?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, datagridcell

If I create a `DataGrid` in code behind with some arbitrary columns added to it I can not get the visual tree to be created for the `DataGrid`. I need to edit the `CellStyle` properties of particular rows dynamically, so I would like to be able to use the `VisualTreeHelper` function on my `DataGrid` objects at run time. How can I build the visual tree for `DataGrid` objects created dynamically? The tree is built with no problems if I use XAML to build one at design-time, but I am not sure how to do this for a dynamic case.

A trivial sample case for my problem is as such:

```
    <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid Name="MainGrid" />
    </Window>
```

With the code behind as:

```
    Class MainWindow
        Dim dg As DataGrid
        Dim col As DataGridTextColumn

        Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()

            col.Header = "HEAD0RR"
            dg.Columns.Add(col)
            MainGrid.Children.Add(dg)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

But the WPF Tree Visualizer just shows the DataGrid I created as having no parents or children, and the VisualTreeHelper function thus does not work.

Comment: try overriding ArrangeOverride if you need to dynamically create the columns, if all you need to do is change a style you could probably override OnRowLoaded

Comment: I just want to add that a simple hack instead of the accepted answer or overriding OnRowLoaded as suggested is to just call the focus() method of the element in order to force the visual tree to be built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tree is built with no problems if I use XAML to build one at
>   design-time, but I am not sure how to do this for a dynamic case.

First of all, "XAML" and "dynamic" are not mutually exclusive. Are you absolutely sure you need build the grid and access CellStyles through procedural (VB) code? There are multiple options from XAML that are easier, more maintainable, and more dynamic than explicitly scanning the visual tree. For example:

- Declare [DataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) per column with [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx)
- Use [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx)s in a [DataGrid.CellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle.aspx), [DataGridColumn.CellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.cellstyle.aspx), or [DataGrid.RowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle.aspx)
- Define alternating / cycling row styles as described at [AlternationCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx)

As for why you can't see items in the visual tree: When are you trying to access it? It won't populate instantly. You may need to wait for the `Loaded` event, or the `StatusChanged` event of the DataGrid's [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx).

Comment: A form I am designing needs to create a new datagrid in response to user input; I am doing this in a tabcontrol which adds a new tabitem containing the newly generated datagrid. This behavior is necessary for the application I am developing, and I was unsure of a method to do this in XAML. I am trying to access the datagrid's child elements after it's creation in the application logic in order to change the cellstyle properties of particular rows generated in the new datagrid object.

Comment: I assume the "particular rows" are identified by the kind of data that they display, so you should be able to define the style differences using DataTriggers. If you need to generate columns dynamically, you could still define the actual styles with DataTriggers in XAML and do something like `col.CellStyle = FindResource("SpecialCellStyle")` where "SpecialCellStyle" is the `x:Key` of your XAML resource.

Comment: Could you point me to a resource to help me figure out how to use XAML to allow new datagrid objects to be created and formatted the way I need so I don't have to do it in code behind? I am also experiencing a similar problem with content I create and add to a tabitem that gets added to a tablist I use as an itemsource for a tabcontrol; anything I create within and including the tabitem does not get a visual tree generated for it for me to use to manipulate child or parent objects with.

Comment: Well, there's a very comprehensive series about ItemsControls (which a DataGrid is one of) [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/). Basically you should get familiar with DataTemplates (which I linked to above) -- they generally eliminate the need to manually insert elements and deal with the visual tree.